# How can i achieve hot deployment in asp .net core mvc project

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am thinking about how can i achieve hot deployement in asp .net core mvc project. I would appreciate if you could answer my question.

Comment: Where you want to Host and deploy the ASP.NET Core application? If you want to deploy the application on IIS, you can simply setup two websites on IIS with same set of settings, when make an update on second website, let the first running, after updating start the second one. You can also refer the blue-green deployments, check [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-5.0). If you deploy the application on Azure web services, you could [set up staging environments](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots).

Comment: Thanks for your help i have solved this problem